# Как циклом менять страницу пока не будет результат

Tags: python, requests

Имеется код, он выдает список. В этом списке есть параметр `id` со значениями

```
import requests

id_find = 114138864
finder = 'ваза'
page = 1

def id_finds(id_find, finder, page):
      url = 'https://search.wb.ru/exactmatch/ru/common/v4/search?' \
            '&appType=1' \
            '&couponsGeo=12,3,18,15,21' \
            '&curr=rub' \
            '&dest=-1029256,-102269,-1282181,-456807' \
            '&emp=0' \
            '&lang=ru' \
            '&locate=ru' \
            '&page=' + str(page) + \
            '&pricemarginCoeff=1.0' \
            '&query=' + finder + \
            '&reg=1' \
            '&regions=80,68,64,83,4,38,33,70,82,69,86,75,30,40,48,1,22,66,31,71' \
            '&resultset=catalog' \
            '&sort=popular' \
            '&spp=27' \
            '&sppFixGeo=4' \
            '&suppressSpellcheck=false'
      res = requests.get(url).json()['data']['products']
      print(res)

id_finds(id_find, finder, page)
```

Как правильно написать цикл, чтобы он изменять `page` пока не найдется `id_find` в этом списке, а после вывести номер данной страницы `page` на которой нашел.
Я пробовал вот такой цикл, но он не удачный

```
     for products in res:
        while id_find != products['id']:
              page +=1
              return page
        else:
              print('done')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests


def id_finds(id_find, finder, page=1):
    while True:
        url = 'https://search.wb.ru/exactmatch/ru/common/v4/search?' \
              '&appType=1' \
              '&couponsGeo=12,3,18,15,21' \
              '&curr=rub' \
              '&dest=-1029256,-102269,-1282181,-456807' \
              '&emp=0' \
              '&lang=ru' \
              '&locate=ru' \
              '&page=' + str(page) + \
              '&pricemarginCoeff=1.0' \
              '&query=' + finder + \
              '&reg=1' \
              '&regions=80,68,64,83,4,38,33,70,82,69,86,75,30,40,48,1,22,66,31,71' \
              '&resultset=catalog' \
              '&sort=popular' \
              '&spp=27' \
              '&sppFixGeo=4' \
              '&suppressSpellcheck=false'
        res = requests.get(url).json()['data']['products']
        for index, x in enumerate(res):
            if id_find == x['id']:
                return page, index
        page += 1


id_find = 114138864
finder = 'ваза'
page, index = id_finds(id_find, finder)
print(f'{page=} {index=}')
```

Comment: Благодарю Сергей!

Comment: Подскажите еще, как найти его index? @Сергей Ш

Comment: Подкорректировал ответ